# JavaScript functions calling each other

Tags: javascript

Just as in topic:

```
function a()
{
     b();
}
function b()
{
     a();
}
```

I tried this but with no succes:

```
function b(){}

function a()
{
     b();
}
function b()
{
     a();
}
```

Any help appreciated ;].

Comment: this is like a simple definition of a stack overflow in javascript :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the first piece of code, other than the fact that it's an infinite recursive loop that'll result in a stack overflow exception.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Its 2-function version of recursion.

Comment: There is code between , i just wanted to clear out the situation. Thanks anyway i must have done the mistake somewhere else...

Comment: It's not the case i just searched for confirmation whether it's correct to do something like this, back in c++ i had to declare a function before calling it like shown in second code block in question.

Comment: So, is your question is about being able to use a function before declaration, or about the infinite recursion? As it currently is, it's not even a question...

Comment: First one, there is nothing to ask about the infinite recursion ; ]

Comment: Okay, so could you edit the question make that clear? I'll add an answer about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're saying this question is about whether or not you're able to call a function in code that appears before its declaration: the answer is **yes**. In JavaScript, variable and function declarations are always hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope. In the case of functions, both the declaration and the definition are hoisted, so:

```
console.log(a); // undefined
console.log(b); // ReferenceError - there is no var b
console.log(f()); // 20;
var a = 10;
console.log(a); // 10
function f() { return 20; }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an endless recursive loop. Bad:

```
function a()
{
     b();
}
function b()
{
     a();
};

a();
```

There. Have fun crashing the browser.

Comment: There is a lot of code between, i just simplified it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying is fine for debugging, but let's make it useful and safe (based on Sam3k's response) :

```
function a(i) { 
  if (i < 10)
  {
     console.log('Running "a" iteration['+i+']');
     b(i);
  }
}

function b(i)
{    
     i++;
     console.log('Running "b" iteration['+i+']');
     a(i);
};

a(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, i dont know how could i just dont run sth like this first ; /